# Font Awesome loading error / Webfont loading issue?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, fonts, font-awesome

I'm currently using font awesome 5.0.9 on a project but I'm stumped as to an issue I'm having.

I have loaded my files as follows;

**File Structure**

```
Root Dir/
 - css/
   - fa-brands.min.css
   - fontawesome-all.min.css
 - js/
 - webfonts/
   - fa-light-300 (All types - eot, svg, ttf etc.)
   - fa-brands-400 (All types - eot, svg, ttf etc.)
   - fa-regular-400 (All types - eot, svg, ttf etc.)
   - fa solid-900 (All types - eot, svg, ttf etc.)
```

**functions.php**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-brands', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/fa-brands.min.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-pro', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/fontawesome-all.min.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
```

**The [icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/lightbulb-on?style=light) I'm trying to use**

```
<span class="d-none d-sm-block btn btn-lg btn-icon btn-white text-primary rounded-circle mb-4">
    <span class="far fa-lightbulb-on btn-icon__inner"></span>
</span>
```

> The icon isn't rendering, I don't even get a square. :(

I have currently,

1. Checked for css overrides (Couldn't see any)
2. Moved my css files into the same folder (didn't work so I moved them back)
3. Checked the fontawesome-all.css file to check the pathing was ok seems fine `example: src:url(../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot)`
4. included `<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"</FilesMatch>` within my .htaccess file.

Chrome's dev tools did point one clue out to me though, I can see in the sources panel all my web-fonts except for `fa-light-300.woff2` (I presume the other types are missing too i.e. fa-light-300.svg etc.). Which would explain why I can use fa-brands, and fa-solid icons without issue.

If someone can help point me in the right direction I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Do you have a link to your project?

Comment: I've figured it out. `<i class="fal fa-lightbulb-on"></i>` wasn't included in FA until version 5.3.0, I was running 5.0.9 updating the files to a later release solved the issue. FML! 3 hours of my life I'll never get back. :@

Comment: Essentially It was looking for an icon that didn't exist.

Comment: Glad you found it out.

Comment: Me too, thanks for the assist! +1 <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<i class="fal fa-lightbulb-on"></i>`

The icon [fa-lightbulb-on](https://fontawesome.com/icons/lightbulb-on?style=light), I was after wasn't included in Font awesome until version 5.3.0. I was running 5.0.9 updating the files to a later release solved the issue in my case (5.8.1). I wish I'd have checked this in the beginning, but hey; we all make mistakes.

Pro Tip: Always check the top of your all.min.css file for the version number and cross check this version with the version number listed at the top of the [cheat sheet](https://fontawesome.com/icons/lightbulb-on?style=light) if you have an icon missing.

[image: Fa version number highlight]